# representing decimal numbers for money exchange rate in Java and Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, precision

We consider two options for saving and doing calculations with money and the currency exchange rate. The options are for the exchange rate:

1 - using whole numbers. multiply each number by 10^7 so what 1.0 will become 10,000,000.
In java it will be a `long`, and in Postgres `BIGINT`

2 - saving the data as it is. In java we use BigDecimal and in postgres `numeric(18,7)`
Any problems that can arise with these options? rounding, overflow, etc.

Comment: Did you check the description of the ISO code for currencies? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

Answer (score -1):

`BigDecimal` is all sorts of complicated. For example, `.equals` doesn't do what you think it does: `a.equals(b)` can return `false` even if `a` and `b` represent the **exact** same amount:

```
BigDecimal zero1 = BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2);
BigDecimal zero2 = BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(3);
System.out.println(zero1.equals(zero2)); // false
System.out.println(zero1.compareTo(zero2)); // 0
```

division is also a bit complicated; without a math context, you can't divide unless the fractional part is divided by a number that consists solely of 2s and 5s if broken down into prime factors. (So, you can't divide by 3, or 15, or 700) - that's because decimal can't represent that (1 divided by 3 is 0.333333 endlessly), and BD mirrors that representative model.

Generally in currency, rounding, of any sort, at any precision, isn't what you want. For example, if the job is to cancel a jointly held account and as part of this job, the amount in the account needs to be distributed equally amongst its owners, then if, say, €1.04 is in the joint account and it is held by 3 people, the right move is to use a random number generator to pick the unlucky loser. That account gets 34 cents, the other two get 35 cents. Or put in the contract that the bank keeps the remainder, so, everybody gets 34 cents, the bank keeps 2 (of course, if the balance was NEGATIVE €1.04, everybody loses 35 cents, the bank gains 1 cent). You can't express this stuff in your number system, you need to express it at the code that does the job (the 'cancel joint account' code needs to explicitly do this).

Also, generally, most financial transactions cannot handle subatomics. I can't transfer half a cent to a bank, so if your storage system can represent half a cent, you're really just kicking the can down the road.

Hence, go with the `long` approach as a general point of principle.

Note, however, that specifically for forex, BD is inevitable. You'd want to read the long out of your DB, then turn that into a BigDecimal and fix the scale (so, 51,000,234 is turned into 5.1000234 again), do the multiplication, and then take that result and go back to `long`, deciding on the spot what to do with any fraction of a cent (round to nearest is usually a bad idea, generally you want to round to favour the system - round down if the customer gets this amount, round up if the customer must pay it. Because if you don't, someone can just make a few million api calls to 'earn' 1 cent every few calls, and fleece the system, that's bad).

So:

- For forex MATH, BigDecimal is correct.
- For storage of financial amounts, `long` is correct (store cents. €1.04 is stored as '104'. Every currency has an atomic. Dollars and euros have cents, pounds have pennies, yen is just yen, bitcoin has satoshis, and so on).
- For storage of forex rates, either one is a defensible choice. But I suggest you use `long`.

Comment: What would be the problem with saving numbers like 5.1000234 in the db in number(18,7) and not in BIGINT?

Comment: Keeping a BigDecimal around for long in a java context (i.e. in fields) is a problem, because they tend to confuse in surreptious ways, such as `equals` not doing what you think it would. BDs model a concept that includes scale, so when you think about a field typed `BigDecimal` and 'yes, scale is an inherent part of that as a semantic concept' __is not__ what you're thinking, then BD is the wrong datatype. So, when reading from the DB, you want to turn that, as you read it, from postgres NUMERIC to `long`, shifting the decimal point accordingly. That's kinda complicated.

Comment: _"BigDecimal is all sorts of complicated."_ - Agree, but disagree on your "solution".  If you're going to work with financial data you MUST understand all the nuances of arithmetic with limited precision. This applies equally to floating point, scaled integers AND `BigDecimal`.  `BigDecimal` will at least tell you via an `ArithmeticException` when you've attempted to represent an unrepresentable number, forcing you to confront rounding behavior.  You will run into exactly the same issues if you use scaled `long`, but then have to keep track of the scale yourself.